# MEF [ImportMany] without Lazy<T,TM>

Tags: .net, mef

Is it possible to access export metadata in MEF without storing
    `IList<Lazy<T,TM>> parts`,
 but simply 
    `IList<T> parts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot get the metadata after the fact. You must import it along with the parts themselves.

Think of the import as a contract specifying the needs of your component. If it needs access to the metadata of some dependency, then you shouldn't hide that.

See also Nicholas Blumhardt's post about [The Relationship Zoo](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/the-relationship-zoo/), where this kind of relationship between components is described as *A needs to know X about B before using it*. The point is that this metadata is an aspect of the relationship between components, not something that should be handled separately somehow.